# Specify the right object and implementation of a virtual function in a macro

Tags: c++, function, oop, macros, abstract-class

I have an abstract class DNXServo and classes XL320 and AX12A which inherit the abstract one and are concrete. Each object of the concrete classes I have in my main corresponds to a serial port on an Arduino Mega and I have 6 servos with unique IDs hooked on each serial port. For the sake of clarity in my code I have the ID of each servo associated with a macro, such as:

```
    // SERIAL 3- hips - AX12A object
    #define HIP_LEFT_FRONT          11
    #define HIP_LEFT_MIDDLE         12
    #define HIP_LEFT_BACK           13
    #define HIP_RIGHT_FRONT         14
    #define HIP_RIGHT_MIDDLE        15
    #define HIP_RIGHT_BACK          16

    // SERIAL 2 - knees - XL320 object
    #define KNEE_LEFT_FRONT         17
    #define KNEE_LEFT_MIDDLE        18
    #define KNEE_LEFT_BACK          19
    #define KNEE_RIGHT_FRONT        20
    #define KNEE_RIGHT_MIDDLE       21
    #define KNEE_RIGHT_BACK         22       
etc.
```

Currently my main looks like this:

```
void setup(){
// Call constructors
    XL320 arms(Serial1, 112500);
    XL320 knees(Serial2, 112500);
    AX12A hips(Serial3, 112500); 
// Write to Servo
    int pos=SetGoalPosition(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT, 250);
}


//return pointer to the object associated with the proper Serial
DNXServo* lookUpServo(int ID){
    if (ID>=11 && ID<=16) return &hips;
    else if (ID>=17 && ID<=22)  return &knees;
    else return &arms;
}

int SetGoalPosition(int ID, int position){
        DNXServo * servo_ptr = lookUpServo(ID);
        return servo_ptr->SetGoalPosition(ID,position);
}
```

SetGoalPosition is actually a virtual member function in DNXServo class and has different concrete implementations in XL320 and AX12A. The case is the same with many other member functions.The problem with my current implementation is that I have to define an additional function in the main for each member function.

Can I avoid that using macros? Ideally, I would like to write sth like

```
SERVO(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT).SetGoalPosition(250);
```

where SetGoalPosition is the name of any member function and automatically call lookUpServo and then call the right implementation of the virtual function.

**EDIT**: `int XL320::SetGoalPosition(int ID, int position)` is the actual definition of the function. Note that it takes two arguments. Therefore I would like `SERVO(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT).SetGoalPosition(250);` to be expanded to sth like `hips.SetGoalPosition(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT, 250);` . As suggested in comments, reference can work as well, but then I would need to always type the ID twice `SERVO(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT).SetGoalPosition(KNEE_LEFT_FRONT, 250);`

Comment: you don't need a macro. `SERVO` should return a reference, that's all. Or I misunderstood something, in which case post a complete (but minimal!) example.

Comment: Thanks. See the edited question.

Comment: I would create a new class for a servo, and initialize it with an id and its connection. Like `joint  left_knee_front(17, knees);`. Then it could easily know how to do `left_knee_front.SetGoalPosition(250);` without any lookup functions.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `SetGoalPosition(int, int)` altogether.  The code calling that should just look like:

```cpp
lookupServo(theId)->SetGoalPosition(42);
```

Then you've solved your problem of "needing to create a function" for every method in the interface.  And though it seems needless to me, a macro for the above would be this

```cpp
#define SERVO(theId) (*(lookupServo(theId)))
```

And now you can write `SERVO(5).SetGoalPosition(42)` as you say you'd like to.

On the other hand, you can just have lookupServo return a reference as someone else mentioned:

```cpp
DNXServo& lookUpServo(int ID) {
    if (ID>=11 && ID<=16) return hips;
    else if (ID>=17 && ID<=22)  return knees;
    else return arms;
}
```

So now you can use a "." instead of the perhaps one could say ugly "->", so that first line I gave you could be a bit improved.

```cpp
lookupServo(theId).SetGoalPosition(42);
```

Note the dot instead of "->".  And the macro, if you still wanted it, could be a little simpler.

```cpp
#define SERVO(theId) (lookupServo(theId))
```

But I would say just go with either the first line of code I showed above and dispense with both SetGoalPosition(int, int) as well as macros, or go with the second version of lookupServo that uses a reference.  There is no need to return a pointer in this case and no good reason to, so I would say the reference version is a little superior.

On a small design note with regard to converting a function that returns a pointer to a function that returns a reference, I would say that you may like the pointer for the ability to return a null pointer, but that is not necessarily an advantage as you can imagine (as in, access violation).  Converting a function to returning a reference means that you impose a contract on yourself to never return null, and this may be a very good thing to express design-wise. In cases where previously you would have returned a null pointer, the question arises what you should do now?  The answer is to throw an exception when you cannot return a valid reference.